# Spring child class PostConstruct method not being called?

Tags: java, spring

I have a hierarchy of classes that all have some implementation of the PostConstruct annotated method, but I've noticed that despite the bean I've defined being an implementation of the lowest level child class, the child class' PostConstruct method is not being called.

I have the following four classes, for example.

```
public class A {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        LOG.info("A PostConstruct complete!");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        super.postConstruct();
        LOG.info("B PostConstruct complete!");
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        super.postConstruct();
        LOG.info("C PostConstruct complete!");
    }
}

public class D extends C {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        super.postConstruct();
        LOG.info("D PostConstruct complete!");
    }
}
```

With this setup, the lines "A PostConstruct complete!" and "B PostConstruct complete!" are printed to the log, but not the C or D lines. However, some methods of the C class are clearly being called, but one specific line at the end of D's PostConstruct method are definitely not getting hit.

I don't know if it matters, but the "LOG" object is a log4j logger.

Comment: Define some method in class D and execute it in your code. I am afraid if this is case of lazy initialization of beans.

Comment: The bean is not being lazy-initialized. Some of its properties are, but that shouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: Have you tested that? which spring version you are using?

Comment: Using Spring 4.2.9 and the bean does not have the lazy-init property in my configuration file. I set it to false on the bean just in case, and there was no change in behavior.

Comment: not sure then but you might be interested in exploring "abstract=true" for defining inheritance in spring way.

Comment: Nevermind. Seems like the thread was getting blocked because of a missing file.